# Struggling to implement threading in kivy app

Tags: kivy, kivymd

I've created a simple scorecard app. However, it takes quite a while to create large scorecards (up to 45 seconds). I'd like to show a popup with a loading animation or something, to tell the user that the scorecard is being created and to wait.

At the moment the user sets the game variables (rounds and players) and then clicks the icon to create the score card (`create_grid()`).

```
<NewGameWindow>:
    name: "new_game"

    MDBoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        
        MDTopAppBar:
            id: nav_bar
            title: "New Game"
            md_bg_color: 28/255, 37/255, 82/255, 1
            left_action_items: [['close', lambda x: app.close()]]
            right_action_items: [['content-save-outline', lambda x: app.create_grid()]]
```

```
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # Main code

    def create_grid(self):
        game_name = self.root.get_screen("new_game").ids['game_name'].text
        rounds = self.root.get_screen("new_game").ids['rounds'].value
        players = self.root.get_screen("new_game").ids['players'].value
        players = int(players)
        rounds = int(rounds)
        self.players = players
        # Calculate cell height and width
        cell_height = dp(48)  # Adjust as needed
        cell_width = Window.width / players  # Adjust as needed

        grid = MDGridLayout(cols=players + 1, size_hint_y=None, adaptive_height=True)
        count_players = 0
        while count_players <= players:
            if count_players == 0:
                cell = MDLabel(text="Round", size_hint_y=None, height=cell_height, width=cell_width)
                cell.font_size = min(cell.width, cell.height) * 0.25
            else:
                cell = MDTextField(text=f"Player{count_players}", size_hint_y=None, height=cell_height, width=cell_width, line_color_normal="blue")
                cell.font_size = min(cell.width, cell.height) * 0.15
            grid.add_widget(cell)
            count_players += 1

        def on_text_changed(instance, value):
            self.update_totals(instance)

        for r in range(rounds):
            cell = MDLabel(text=f"{r+1}", size_hint_y=None, height=cell_height, width=cell_width)
            cell.font_size = min(cell.width, cell.height) * 0.35
            grid.add_widget(cell)
            for _ in range(players):
                cell = MDTextField(text="0", size_hint_y=None, height=cell_height, width=cell_width)
                cell.font_size = min(cell.width, cell.height) * 0.25
                cell.bind(text=on_text_changed)
                grid.add_widget(cell)

        total_row = 0

        for _ in range(players + 1):
            if total_row == 0:
                cell = MDLabel(text="Total", size_hint_y=None, height=cell_height, width=cell_width)
            else:
                cell = MDLabel(text="0", size_hint_y=None, height=cell_height, width=cell_width)
            cell.font_size = min(cell.width, cell.height) * 0.35
            grid.add_widget(cell)
            total_row += 1


        self.root.get_screen("scorecard").ids['add_table_to_scrollview'].add_widget(grid)
        self.calculate_grid_height(grid)  # Calculate and set the height of the grid layout
        self.sm.current = "scorecard"

        scorecard_data = []
        for i in grid.children:
            scorecard_data.append(i.text)
        scorecard_data.reverse()
        scorecard_data = str(scorecard_data)

        # Save the scorecard to the database
        conn = sqlite3.connect('scorecard.db')
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("INSERT INTO scorecard (GAME_NAME, NUMBER_OF_PLAYERS, NUMBER_OF_ROUNDS, SCORECARD) "
                  "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);", (game_name, players, rounds, scorecard_data))
        c.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid()")
        game_id_tuple = c.fetchone()
        self.game_id = int(game_id_tuple[0]) # last_insert_rowid() returns a single value tuple, we have to convert it to an int
        conn.commit()
        conn.close()


    def update_totals(self, instance):
        grid = self.root.get_screen("scorecard").ids['add_table_to_scrollview'].children[0]
        values = []

        counter = 0
        for g in reversed(grid.children): # Have to reverse the order otherwise it starts from the final cell
            if counter > self.players:
                if isinstance(g, MDTextField):
                    try:
                        score = int(g.text) # Convert the text of the cell to an integer so it can be summed
                        values.append(score)
                    except:
                        values.append(0)
            else:
                counter += 1

        loop = 1
        for t in range(self.players):
            total_cell = grid.children[self.players - loop]
            player_total = sum(values[t::self.players]) # Jump through the list by the number of players
            total_cell.text = str(player_total)
            loop += 1
```

I've tried adding `@mainthread` to my `create_grid` function as suggested here: [Avoid : Cannot create graphics instruction outside the main Kivy thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72467172/avoid-cannot-create-graphics-instruction-outside-the-main-kivy-thread) but it's still freezing the app.

I thought I could use threading on the popup but then the main app would still freeze and I assume best practice would be to have the heavy process on the thread and the popup on the mainthread, waiting for the thread to complete.

I've tried adding the `create_grid` function to a thread but as it contains a lot of code to create kivy graphics (widgets) it doesn't allow me to do this outside of the mainthread.

Comment: what is the indentation level of " def on_text_changed(instance, value):"  it looks like it is incorrectly indented.  it also looks like you don't have complete code here to run.  your build method has the comment "# Main code" but build is supposed to return your top-level Widget such as Screen Manager or box layout, it is not  the 'main' of  your App.
you are correct in that a separate thread should be used to perform database operations.

Comment: That's correctly indented, it's an inner function of ```create_grid```. I just added in ```# Main code``` rather than show many lines of unnesseary code. I'm just not sure on the threading side of things, as the above question